# Changing Default Environment Setting when starting Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Today I installed Visual Studio 2010 on a new machine.

When starting VS2010 for first time, it asked for "Default Environment Window" I selected "Visual C# Development Settings" from it by mistake.

[image]

But now i want to change that setting to "Visual Basic Development Settings". How can i do so?

Comment: I would have preferred you ask it the other way (I chose VB by mistake, now want C#). I'll +1 you but this is not an endorsement of VB!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simplest way to go, AFAIK, is: Tools -> Import/Export Settings -> Reset All Settings.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you saw this, but it may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx

From that page, there's this instruction:

> On the Tools menu, click Import and Export Settings.
>
> If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose No,
> just reset settings, overwriting my current settings, and then click
> Next. This option does not delete default settings, which will still
> be available the next time you use the wizard.