# Visual Studio 2012 "Reset All Settings" Bug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I´m having the problem described in this post:
[Changing Default Enviromnent Setting when starting Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084958/changing-default-enviromnent-setting-when-starting-visual-studio-2010)

My bigger problem is that I cannot reset the IDE settings.
If I click on **Tools => Import and Export Settings ... => Reset All Settings => Next** the window just closes and nothing happens (I have started vs as admin).

I´m using VS 2012 Premium.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to reset all settings, see if loading new defaults and overwriting your old settings works for you:

- Tools => Import and Export Settings
- Import selected environment settings
- No, just import new settings, overwriting my current settings
- Select [Desired Defaults]
- Next
- Finish

Comment: When I click on import => next the window also closes immediately and nothing happens

Comment: Ah then in that case the only thing I can say is to try repairing your installation of Visual Studio. Then try again. Or just uninstall completely and reinstall.